# View elements id's

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm having problems retrieving the "id" from the OrderProduct element in the XML file below in C# using LINQ to XML. I've tried a simpler XML file and was able to retrieve multiple elements.

The C# only retrieves the first id=542 and doesn't loop to the id=543. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

---[ order.xml ]-----------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<OrderXml>
  <Order ... >
    .
    .
    .
    <OrderProducts>
      <OrderProduct id="542"></OrderProduct>
      <OrderProduct id="543"></OrderProduct>
    </OrderProducts>
  </Order>
</OrderXml>
```

---[ C# ]-----------------------

```
IEnumerable<XElement> OrderXml = xelement.Elements ();

foreach (var order in OrderXml)
  Console.WriteLine ("id: {0}", order.Element ("OrderProducts").Element ("OrderProduct").Attribute ("id").Value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to set the pointer in the right place:

Look at [`Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx)

```
foreach (var order in OrderXml.Descendants("OrderProducts"))
{
    Console.WriteLine ("id: {0}", order.Element("OrderProduct").Attribute("id").Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);

var productIds = from p in xdoc.Descendants("OrderProduct")
                 select (int)p.Attribute("id");

foreach (var id in productIds)
     Console.WriteLine ("id: {0}", id);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
var ids = from el in OrderXml.Descendants("OrderProduct") select el.Attribute("id").Value;

foreach (var id in ids)
{
    Console.WriteLine("id: {0}", id);
}
```